# Can I control 5050 RGB Strips with the Raspberry pi?

Tags: gpio, led, electronics

I have purchased [5 meters of a 5050 RGB Strip](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B00HJ2KC96/ref=ox_sc_act_title_4?smid=A2FDPRAQE1CP9M&psc=1) yesterday. I bought it for my PC case, but of course I don't want to use 5 meters in my case.

I want to do some smart lighting in my room and a bias light for [my RPi Mediacenter](https://youtu.be/-ZflCfHNwTM). However, I only found tutorials on how to control WS2812 LEDS, which run at 5 Volts.

But how can I control those 5050 Strips, running at 12 Volts. Would be great if someone knew that.

Comment: I was looking for the same and found this page which seems to tackle the problem: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/242768/raspberry-pi-irfz44n-to-control-a-5050-rgb-led-strip-current-seems-to-be-limi

Answer (score 0):

It looks good except a lot depends on which IFRZ44s you get. Its turn on voltage is from 2 to 4 volts. On a good day your pie has 3.3 volts so if they work expect them to get hot. Since you have not purchased them yet pick something with a lower Vgs requirement or use a gate driver IC.